# Java- ¿Cómo puedo hacer un arreglo de imágenes? Interfaz

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo un proyecto de hacer una lista que haga sus respectivas funciones el problema es que me pidieron que se haga con 2 arreglos, uno de elementos y otro de imágenes con flechas para hacer que estas hagan la función de puntero; el profesor nos dijo que se puede hacer un arreglo de imágenes que puedan ponerse visibles o invisibles en función del índice del arreglo donde están los elementos (no nos enseñó a hacerlo) mi programa de lista funciona pero no sé cómo hacer el arreglo de imágenes con las flechas para cuando deba buscar un elemento en la lista, borrarlo, etc. este esté apuntado por una flecha. si alguien puede ayudar muchas gracias. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]`

```
package estructuradedatos;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author HP15AW0
 */
public class Lista extends javax.swing.JFrame {
DefaultListModel modeloLista;

public Lista() {
    initComponents();
    modeloLista=new DefaultListModel();
    JlistaValor.setModel(modeloLista);
}
public void agregarValor(){
String valor=txtInsertar.getText();
modeloLista.addElement(valor);
}
public void quitarValor(){
   int respues=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Realmente desea quitar el varlo?");
if (respues==0){
   int pos=JlistaValor.getSelectedIndex();
modeloLista.remove(pos);
    /*int pos=0;
modeloLista.remove(pos);*/
}

 }

public void buscarValor(){
String valor=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el valor que quiera buscar");
modeloLista.contains(valor);
if ( modeloLista.contains(valor)){

    txtShow.setText("El valor "+valor+" ha sido encontrado");
    }else{
    txtShow.setText("El valor que usted busca no ha sido encontrado");
}


}

 public void leerTamaño(){
   int tamaño=modeloLista.size();
   txtShow.setText("El tamaño de la lista es "+tamaño);

}
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    JlistImagen = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    Insertarbtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Eliminarbtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    buscarbtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    tamañobtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    JlistaValor = new javax.swing.JList();
    txtShow = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txtInsertar = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Lista");

    JlistImagen.setEditable(false);

    Insertarbtn.setText("Insertar");
    Insertarbtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            InsertarbtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Eliminarbtn.setText("Eliminar");
    Eliminarbtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            EliminarbtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    buscarbtn.setText("Buscar");
    buscarbtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            buscarbtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    tamañobtn.setText("Tamaño");
    tamañobtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            tamañobtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(JlistaValor);

    txtShow.setEditable(false);
    txtShow.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtShowActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txtInsertar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtInsertarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(24, 24, 24)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(JlistImagen, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(txtInsertar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 101, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(Eliminarbtn)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(tamañobtn))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(Insertarbtn)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(buscarbtn)))
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                    .addContainerGap(74, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(79, 79, 79)
                    .addComponent(txtShow)
                    .addContainerGap())))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(txtInsertar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(Insertarbtn)
                .addComponent(buscarbtn))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 221, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(JlistImagen)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(Eliminarbtn)
                        .addComponent(tamañobtn))))
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addComponent(txtShow, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(65, 65, 65))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void InsertarbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    agregarValor();
}                                           

private void EliminarbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    quitarValor();
}                                           

private void buscarbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    buscarValor();
}                                         

private void tamañobtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    leerTamaño();
}                                         

private void txtInsertarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void txtShowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Lista.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Lista.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Lista.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Lista.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Lista().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton Eliminarbtn;
private javax.swing.JButton Insertarbtn;
private javax.swing.JTextField JlistImagen;
private javax.swing.JList JlistaValor;
private javax.swing.JButton buscarbtn;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JButton tamañobtn;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtInsertar;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtShow;
// End of variables declaration                   
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo realizar los siguientes pasos:

Paso 1:

Incluye la siguiente línea al principio del código Java:

```
import org.apache.commons.io. IOUtils;
```

Paso 2:

Abre el archivo que contenga la imagen como un FileInputStream Java, como en el código de ejemplo siguiente:

```
FileInputStream myStream = new FileInputStream("imageFile.jpg");
```

Paso 3:

Lee la secuencia de entrada en una matriz de bytes llamando al método de la librería ToByteArray (), como en el siguiente ejemplo de código:

```
byte[] imageInBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(myStream);
```

La matriz de bytes "imageInBytes" contendrá los bytes correspondientes al archivo de imagen.

Comment: Así es como importas las imágenes al programa? es necesario que estén afuera de la carpeta de src? y he usado comandos en mi lista (sacados de una guía) cómo puedo hacer que el arreglo de imágenes esté en función de mis "valores"? disculpa el exceso de preguntas, gracias por apoyar.

Answer (score 0):

Realice un programa que barajea cartas de poker, el punto es que utilize un arreglo de imagenes para esto ya que aunque eran solo 14 cartas si lo hacia manualmente iba a escribir demasiado codigo aqui esta mi ejemplo:

```
    public class cartas extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form cartas
     */
    public cartas() {
        initComponents();
      reinicio.setEnabled(false);
    }
     /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
       //CREACION DE JLabels LAS CUALES CONTENDRAN LAS IMAGENES.......
        carta1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        carta2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        carta3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        carta4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        carta5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        carta6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        carta7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        carta8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        carta9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        carta10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        carta11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        carta12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        carta13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        carta14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Inicio = new javax.swing.JButton();
        mesa4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        mesa1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        mesa2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        mesa3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        reinicio = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        //Posicionamiento-....................
        carta1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/AsRojo.png")));
        getContentPane().add(carta1);
        carta1.setBounds(30, 10, 100, 139);

        carta2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/Rojo2.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(carta2);
        carta2.setBounds(30, 10, 100, 140);

        carta3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/Rojo3.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(carta3);
        carta3.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 140);

        carta4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/Rojo4.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(carta4);
        carta4.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 140);

        carta5.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/Rojo5.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(carta5);
        carta5.setBounds(30, 10, 100, 140);

        carta6.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta6.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/carta1.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(carta6);
        carta6.setBounds(20, 10, 100, 140);

        carta7.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta7.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/carta2.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(carta7);
        carta7.setBounds(40, 10, 100, 140);

        carta8.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta8.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/carta3.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(carta8);
        carta8.setBounds(30, 10, 100, 140);

        carta9.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta9.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/carta4.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(carta9);
        carta9.setBounds(40, 10, 100, 140);

        carta10.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta10.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/carta5.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(carta10);
        carta10.setBounds(20, 10, 100, 140);

        carta11.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta11.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/carta6.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(carta11);
        carta11.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 140);

        carta12.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta12.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/carta7.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(carta12);
        carta12.setBounds(30, 10, 100, 140);

        carta13.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta13.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/carta8.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(carta13);
        carta13.setBounds(30, 10, 100, 140);

        carta14.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        carta14.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/carta9.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(carta14);
        carta14.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 139);

        Inicio.setText("Repartir");
        Inicio.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                InicioActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(Inicio);
        Inicio.setBounds(660, 30, 72, 25);

        mesa4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        mesa4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/cartaVolteada2.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(mesa4);
        mesa4.setBounds(550, 100, 100, 135);

        mesa1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        mesa1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/cartaVolteada2.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(mesa1);
        mesa1.setBounds(220, 100, 100, 135);

        mesa2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        mesa2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/cartaVolteada2.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(mesa2);
        mesa2.setBounds(330, 100, 100, 135);

        mesa3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        mesa3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/carta/cartaVolteada2.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(mesa3);
        mesa3.setBounds(440, 100, 100, 135);
         //Boton...................
        reinicio.setText("Reinicio");
        reinicio.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                reinicioActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(reinicio);
        reinicio.setBounds(560, 30, 71, 25);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void InicioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // Evento boton reinicio..................
    //Creacion de un objeto de la clase repartir,
    //El constructor de esa clase requiere 18 argumentos JLabel
    repartir repa = new repartir(carta1, carta2, carta3, carta4, carta5, carta6, carta7,
                carta8, carta9, carta10, carta11, carta12, carta13, carta14,
                mesa1, mesa2, mesa3, mesa4);
        //Metodo que llena el arreglo-----
        repa.llenado();
        //Metodo que barajea las cartas y las posiciona en la pantalla
        repa.visibilidad();
        //Metodo que muestra y posiciona las cartas de la maquina o Dealer....
        repa.maquina();
        //Despues de repartir las cartas se habilita el boton para reiniciar todo
        reinicio.setEnabled(true);
        // }
    }                                      
//Boton reinicio
    private void reinicioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        //Regresa todos los componentes a su lugar inicial
        repartir rehacer= new repartir(carta1,carta2,carta3,carta4,carta5,carta6,carta7,
                                   carta8,carta9,carta10,carta11,carta12,carta13,carta14,
                                   mesa1,mesa2,mesa3,mesa4);
        rehacer.llenado();
        rehacer.reinicio();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(cartas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(cartas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(cartas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(cartas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                cartas carta=new cartas();
                carta.setVisible(true);
                carta.setBounds(0,0,783,477);
                carta.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton Inicio;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta14;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta9;
    private javax.swing.JLabel mesa1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel mesa2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel mesa3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel mesa4;
    private javax.swing.JButton reinicio;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Clase repartir, en este proyecto tiene algunos detalles que corregir pero el arreglo funciona correctamente, el detalle esta en el posicionamiento de algunas componentes y en el numero random que pido:

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author erikj
 */
public class repartir {
    public int carta1,carta2,carta3,carta4;
    public int mesa1=0,mesa2=0,mesa3=0,mesa4=0,contador=0,nlista1=0,nlista2=0,nlista3=0,nlista4=0,random=0;
    //Declaro el arreglo:
    public JLabel[]arreglo=new JLabel[14];
    public JLabel baraja1,baraja2,baraja3,baraja4,baraja5,baraja6,baraja7,
                 baraja8,baraja9,baraja10,baraja11,baraja12,baraja13,baraja14,
                 dealer1,dealer2,dealer3,dealer4;
    Random numerosAleatorios = new Random();
    //Constructor que recibira los parametros de JLabel:................
    public repartir(JLabel mano1,JLabel mano2,JLabel mano3,JLabel mano4,JLabel mano5,
                    JLabel mano6,JLabel mano7,JLabel mano8,JLabel mano9,JLabel mano10,
                    JLabel mano11,JLabel mano12,JLabel mano13,JLabel mano14, JLabel CartaMesa1,
                    JLabel CartaMesa2,JLabel CartaMesa3,JLabel CartaMesa4){
        this.baraja1=mano1;
        this.baraja2=mano2;
        this.baraja3=mano3;
        this.baraja4=mano4;
        this.baraja5=mano5;
        this.baraja6=mano6;
        this.baraja7=mano7;
        this.baraja8=mano8;
        this.baraja9=mano9;
        this.baraja10=mano10;
        this.baraja11=mano11;
        this.baraja12=mano12;
        this.baraja13=mano13;
       this.baraja14=mano14;
       this.dealer1=CartaMesa1;
       this.dealer2=CartaMesa2;
       this.dealer3=CartaMesa3;
       this.dealer4=CartaMesa4;
    }
    //Llenado de el arreglo:
    public void llenado(){
        arreglo[0]=baraja1;
         arreglo[1]=baraja2;
          arreglo[2]=baraja3;
           arreglo[3]=baraja4;
           arreglo[4]=baraja5;
         arreglo[5]=baraja6;
          arreglo[6]=baraja7;
           arreglo[7]=baraja8;
           arreglo[8]=baraja9;
         arreglo[9]=baraja10;
          arreglo[10]=baraja11;
           arreglo[11]=baraja12;
           arreglo[12]=baraja13;
           arreglo[13]=baraja14;
    }
    //METODO Repartir cartas para el USUARIO --- NO MODIFICAR
    public void visibilidad() {
        int valorAleatorio = numerosAleatorios.nextInt(14);
        do {
            contador += 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
                if (contador == 1) {
                    if (valorAleatorio == i) {
                        arreglo[i].setLocation(200, 300);
                        arreglo[i].setVisible(true);
                        nlista1 = valorAleatorio;
                        System.out.println("nlista 1 " + nlista1);
                        i = 14;

                    }
                } else if (contador == 2) {
                    if (valorAleatorio == i) {
                        if (valorAleatorio == nlista1) {
                            valorAleatorio = numerosAleatorios.nextInt(14);
                            i = 0;
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            arreglo[i].setLocation(300, 300);
                            arreglo[i].setVisible(true);
                            nlista2 = valorAleatorio;
                            System.out.println("nlista 2 " + nlista2);
                            i = 14;
                        }
                    }

                } else if (contador == 3) {
                    if (valorAleatorio == i) {
                        if (valorAleatorio == nlista1 | valorAleatorio == nlista2) {
                            valorAleatorio = numerosAleatorios.nextInt(14);
                            i = 0;
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            arreglo[i].setLocation(400, 300);
                            arreglo[i].setVisible(true);
                            nlista3 = valorAleatorio;
                            System.out.println("nlista 3 " + nlista3);
                            i = 14;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (contador == 4) {
                    if (valorAleatorio == i) {
                        if (valorAleatorio == nlista1 | valorAleatorio == nlista2 | valorAleatorio == nlista3) {
                            valorAleatorio = numerosAleatorios.nextInt(14);
                            i = 0;
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            arreglo[i].setLocation(500, 300);
                            arreglo[i].setVisible(true);
                            nlista4 = valorAleatorio;
                            System.out.println("nlista 4 " + nlista4);
                            i = 14;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            valorAleatorio = numerosAleatorios.nextInt(14);
        } while (contador < 4);
        contador = 0;
        ///NO MODIFICAR ESTE METODO
    }

    ///MODIFICANDO-------------------------------------------------
    public void maquina() {
        random = numerosAleatorios.nextInt(14);
        do {
            System.out.println("Numero aleatorio inicio del do: " + random);
            contador += 1;
            System.out.println("Contador " + contador);
            for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
                if (contador == 1) {
                    if (random == i) {
                        if (random == nlista1 | random == nlista2 | random == nlista3 | random == nlista4) {
                            random = numerosAleatorios.nextInt(14);
                            i = 0;
                            System.out.println("If malo 1: " + random);
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            //DEALER1= CARTA VOLTEADA 1
                            dealer1.setVisible(false);
                            dealer1.setLocation(10, 170);
                            arreglo[i].setLocation(220, 100);
                            mesa1 = random;
                            i = 14;
                            System.out.println("Dealer 1: " + mesa1);

                        }
                    }
                } else if (contador == 2) {
                    if (random == i) {
                        if (random == nlista1 | random == nlista2 | random == nlista3 |
                           random == nlista4 | random == mesa1) {
                            random = numerosAleatorios.nextInt(14);
                            i = 0;
                            System.out.println("If malo 2: " + random);
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            dealer2.setVisible(false);
                            dealer2.setLocation(10, 170);
                            arreglo[i].setLocation(330, 100);
                            mesa2 = random;
                            i = 14;
                            //Indicacion de numero
                            System.out.println("Dealer 2: " + mesa2);
                        }
                    }

                } else if (contador == 3) {
                    if (random == i) {
                        if (random == nlista1 | random == nlista2 | random == nlista3 |
                            random == nlista4 | random == mesa1 | random == mesa2) {
                            random = numerosAleatorios.nextInt(14);
                            i = 0;
                            
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            dealer3.setVisible(false);
                            dealer3.setLocation(10, 170);
                            arreglo[i].setLocation(440, 100);
                            mesa3 = random;
                            i = 14;
                            System.out.println("Dealer 3: " + mesa3);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (contador == 4) {
                    if (random == i) {
                        if (random == nlista1 | random == nlista2 | random == nlista3 | random == nlista4
                                | random == mesa1 | random == mesa2 | random == mesa3) {
                            random = numerosAleatorios.nextInt(14);
                            i = 0;
                            System.out.println("If malo 4: " + random);
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            dealer4.setVisible(false);
                            dealer4.setLocation(10, 170);
                            arreglo[i].setLocation(550, 100);
                            mesa4 = random;
                            i = 14;
                            System.out.println("Dealer 4: " + mesa4);
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Numero aleatorio debajo del for " + random);
            }
            random = numerosAleatorios.nextInt(14);
        } while (contador < 4);

    }

    public void reinicio() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            arreglo[i].setLocation(30, 10);
        }
        mesa1 = 0;
        mesa2 = 0;
        mesa3 = 0;
        mesa4 = 0;
        nlista1 = 0;
        nlista2 = 0;
        nlista3 = 0;
        nlista4 = 0;
    }

}
```